# VS Error: "You must choose a publish location that is different from the source Web application"

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008, wcf

I'm trying to publish my WCF service to a server on my network:

> http://machineName/ProjectName

The most recent (first) version of the service is already there as I did this no more than 15 minutes ago. I then made some changes to the service's web.config and one setting in IIS and now I can't publish the service anymore, getting the error returned in the title.

web.config changes:

Changed

```
<service name="ProjectName.Service1"...
```

to

```
<service name="ProjectName.ServiceName"...
```

IIS change: changed application name from nothing to ProjectName

What happened?

Comment: Are you sure the publish location didn't "accidentally" change to the local path?  That seems the most likely conclusion.

Comment: Indeed I'm sure, I've tried a number of times.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Solved**

Turns out that I had originally tried to set it up via the project properties UI.

"Project Properties>Web>Use IIS Web server" was selected and I had the address of the server in the "Project URL:" textbox. clearing this out solved the issue.

Comment: Additional info: had a similar problem, but in my case it was not enough to change the settings and clear the address in the Project Properties window. I had to open the project file in Notepad and delete the <IISUrl> tag from there.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're trying to publish the web site to the directory the same project is being loaded from.